# How to implement calendar in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

Can anybody tell how to implement calendar in sencha touch .I am following this link https://github.com/SwarmOnline/Ext.ux.TouchCalendar to bring calendar in application

**In index.hmtl I have included**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/Ext.ux.TouchCalendarView.css" media="all"/>
        <script src="../Ext.ux.TouchCalendarView.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
    <script src="../Ext.ux.TouchCalendar.js" type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"></script>
```

In Main.js am calling calendar view

```
{
                title: 'Details',
                iconCls: 'info',
                **xtype: 'calendar',**
                //style: 'margin-left:25%;',
                cls: 'card dark'
                },
```

the calendar is not coming in my screen is there any thing am missing please help to solve this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to site https://market.sencha.com/extensions and download **Calander Pro** component example and you can use it. It will completely help you.

For download you need to account on sencha.

Comment: And also pay for it!!